# How to solve the error "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Tags: python, git, repository, bitbucket, conda

I have cloned a git repository and created a new project in pycharm.
Now, i have created a new experimental branch in bitbucket and want to git checkout locally.

Hence, I use "

> git checkout feature/MLJ-62-move-merging-of-reoccurring-layouts"

But I have this error,

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

What I do:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you run git commands in cloned directory(that has .git in it).

Answer (score -2):

this happens when git can't find the branch name.